# Can I allow additional arguments in an operatorfunc?

Tags: map-operator

To call a custom operator with a mapping, one can do

```
nnoremap <Plug>(Foo) :set opfunc=Baa<CR>g@
```

so that `<Plug>(Foo)` expects a motion, after which the function `Baa` is called.
Here, `Baa` takes in a single `type` argument, and processes the `'[` and `']` marks accordingly.

Now, how can I add argument(s) to `Baa`, and call it with a mapping?

That is, suppose I have

```
function! Baa(type, arg1)
  " do stuff ...
  " process a:arg1
endfunction
```

How would I map `<Plug>(Foo)`?
(`arg1` is allowed to vary, depending on the context.)

Answer (score 2):

`operatorfunc` is very limited and can't take arguments or be set to e.g., lambdas.  A "standard" way to handle this situation is to use an expression map to a setup wrapper function, and keep the argument in a global or script-context variable.  This means unfortunately that the operator is not reentrant, but this is rarely needed.

This is the approach taken in the popular plugin vim-commentary: [[1](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/349340debb34f6302931f0eb7139b2c11dfdf427/plugin/commentary.vim#L102)].

Here is another example of a "repeatable command" which is similar to an operator that takes arguments:

```
function! RepWincmd(...)
    execute (v:count ? v:count : s:state[1]) 'wincmd' s:state[0]
endfunction

function! s:setup(rep, ...)
    let s:state = [a:rep, v:count ? v:count : get(a:000, 0, 1)]
    set operatorfunc=RepWincmd
    return 'g@l'
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <c-w>- <sid>setup('-', 3)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>+ <sid>setup('+', 3)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>< <sid>setup('<', 5)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>> <sid>setup('>', 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, I suspected that opfuncs would not have such functionality.

(1) vim-commentary uses multiple arguments, to allow for multiple purposes: 
to call itself, use as an operator, or with a range. However, 
those variable arguments are used for a different purposes from what I have in mind.

(2) Accessing via a script or global variable is what I was seeking. Though it seems unnatural (since it is external from the function), it is a viable option.

(3) Nice tip to use an operator for repeatability!